# SQL numeric/decimal to boost multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost

I'm looking for some (non-string) type in C++ that we can use to store a SQL `numeric(18, 4)` (or `decimal(18, 4)`) value. I went through the documentation of boost's [cpp_dec_float](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/floats/cpp_dec_float.html), but am still quite confused about how to use it:

- When the doc says "decimal digits" (e.g. in "The typedefs cpp_dec_float_50 and cpp_dec_float_100 provide arithmetic types at 50 and 100 decimal digits precision respectively"), is it referring to the number of digits to the right of the decimal point or *all* the significant digits?
- `std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<50>>>::digits10` is 50 but `std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<4>>>::digits10` is 9. Why is that?
- If the `Digits10` template parameter is the number of *all* significant digits, does it mean there is no way to specify a fixed precision and a scale (as in SQL `numeric(18, 4)`) for boost multiprecision types?

Comment: "std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<50>>> is 50"  Huh?  `std::numeric_limits<T>` is a structure type, not a single number.

Comment: @BenVoigt My bad, that was a typo. Corrected.

Comment: The documentation directly says "The actual precision of a cpp_dec_float is always slightly higher than the number of digits specified in the template parameter, actually how much higher is an implementation detail but is always at least 8 decimal digits. "

Comment: @BenVoigt So since `std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<50>>>::digits10 == 50`, I suppose the "decimal digits" in the doc means *all* the significant digits then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the doc says "decimal digits" (e.g. in "The typedefs cpp_dec_float_50 and cpp_dec_float_100 provide arithmetic types at 50 and 100 decimal digits precision respectively"), is it referring to the number of digits to the right of the decimal point or all the significant digits?

All the significant digits.

> std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<50>>>::digits10 is 50 but std::numeric_limits<number<cpp_dec_float<4>>>::digits10 is 9. Why is that?

It's an implementation detail. Basically, the library provides the minimum it requires to deliver you the promised 4 digits

> If the Digits10 template parameter is the number of all significant digits, does it mean there is no way to specify a fixed precision and a scale (as in SQL numeric(18, 4)) for boost multiprecision types?

Indeed. In short, the multi-precision library does not provide any fixed-point types (though you can obviously make your own with something like [`cpp_int`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/tut/ints/cpp_int.html))